# How to iterate API data using ngFor in Angular 2

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am new in Angular 2 and I want to display all the API data in tabular form.
Here is my working code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/CB3oGppm4fvoEExfDSRc?p=preview

But when I am using this code in my files, I am having an error:

> Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'any[]'

**test.component.html:**

```
<h1>{{getData[0]?.name}}</h1>
<h1>{{getData[0]?.time}}</h1>
<div *ngFor="let item of getData">
  <span>{{item?.name}}</span>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { ConfigurationService } from './ConfigurationService';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
  getData = [];

   constructor(private _ConfigurationService: ConfigurationService)
    {
        console.log("Reading _ConfigurationService ");
        //console.log(_ConfigurationService.getConfiguration());

         this._ConfigurationService.getConfiguration()
            .subscribe(
            (data)=> {
                this.getData = data; 
                console.log(this.getData);
            },
            (error) => console.log("error : " + error)
        );
    }
}
```

This code is working in Plunkr but having error when I try it in my project. Please help to iterate the API values in my project. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the code line where you are having this error? Not in the plunker but in your code.

Comment: print the response and check format because u might not getting array of response.You might be getting any[] within the response object

Comment: @echonax Module build failed: Error: app.component.ts (20,17): Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'any[]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you haven't assigned type to your `getData` variable. If you change `getData = [];` to `getData: any = [];`, your code should work. Other solution is to change compiler options in your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false
}
```

If you set `noImplicitAny` to `false`, you don't have to assign type to variables, if you don't implicitly set variable's type, it will be set to `any` automatically.

Comment: @vinayofficial but that doesn't entirely solve the problem, because the signature of `getConfiguration` still doesn't *actually reflect what it returns*.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of your service method `getConfiguration` is

```
(): Observable<Response>
```

But the return type is not correct, it should be the type that the Observable will materialize. Example:

```
(): Observable<any[]>
```

You can make `any` a specific type.

Comment: @vinayofficial - I am glad it worked for you. This is the correct way to do it and maintain type safety. Casting to `any` is usually not recommended if you know the type you are returning.